# Php Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'fobos'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql

I have problems with connecting to the Mysql database (v5 and v8). If user is root that it's ok but if I create user 'fobos' I have connection error 1045 (error message `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'fobos'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in vms\public\staff\visitors\vms.php on line 14`). I have no idea why this is happening.

**Mysql -> create user fobos**

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user

+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| fobos            | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+

 CREATE USER 'fobos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$zP_jaGA5xAE@"8~7TpdM';
    
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON visitor_managment_system.*
        TO 'fobos'@'localhost'
        IDENTIFIED BY '$zP_jaGA5xAE@"8~7TpdM';
```

**php**

```
   public function __construct() {
    
        $this->connect = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = visitor_managment_system","fobos", '$zP_jaGA5xAE@\"8~7TpdM');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try FLUSH PRIVILEGES command in mysql cli

Comment: Okay try checking stackoverflow it has all the answers